# Who was Queen Ester's son with Achashverosh?

Tags: esther--the-woman

Is he the one who permitted the construction of the Second Temple? Did she have only one son with the king?

Comment: https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/306/Q6/ https://www.jewishhistory.org/the-beginning-2nd-commonwealth/

Comment: Why do you think she had a son?

Comment: https://www.thetorah.com/article/ahasuerus-and-vashti-the-story-megillat-esther-does-not-tell-you

Answer (score 1):

> Who was Queen Ester's son with Achashverosh?

There are traditions that Esther's son was Darius (Tosafoth RH 3b, DH shenath, Leviticus Rabbah 13:5). This would mean that Darius, as the son of a Jewish woman, was a Jew. However this is difficult to reconcile with the Talmud's treatment of his actions (vis a vis his intentions in the bringing of sacrifices) through the lens of identifying him as a gentile (RH 3b).

R. Jacob Hagiz (Halakhoth Qetanoth 2:240) suggests that insofar as he was raised as a gentile, he is treated as a mumar (apostate). And that a mumar, in the Talmud's case here, is treated as a gentile. In which case, though he was as the son of Esther a Jew, he is nevertheless *treated as a gentile*.

> Is he the one who permitted the construction of the Second Temple?

Yes, according to this tradition, it is the same Darius.

> Did she have only one son with the king?

I do not believe there is any known evidence of any additional children.

Comment: According to an opinion in another Midrash https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%98_%D7%99%D7%92 she was 40 when she married Achashverosh so probably not that many kids (but most opinions say ~75 years old in which case no kids)

Comment: @DoubleAA though not dispositive, those are certainly good points. Thanks